# Changing the color of Activity in windows workflow designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation

I am rehosting a workflow designer. I want to change the color of the tasks after their completion. This is my [designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEzSw.png)  before execution and after the execution i want to change it like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEWkM.png) I have also seen such thing in SSIS. So is it possible in windows workflow?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create an activity designer project. With a WF activity designer item, you can use WPF to style your custom activities, as well as even provide your own designed versions of the built-in activity types provided out of the box with WF.